# Collision between two balls

Tags: android, collision-detection

I want to simulate a collision between two balls, one controlled by the accelerometer and the other just moving randomly.
How do I implement these collisions? I've managed to set up the balls and the condition for collision, but beyond that, I have no idea how I can represent the collision vectors. An algorithm or a hint would be appreciated :) I have the x and y velocities and positions of the two balls stored in variables. I also managed to use some basic (yet wrong) collision mechanism, the random motion ball reverses its x and y velocities. But I'm having problems there too, if the balls are moving too fast, they overlap. What do I do?

```
package perseus.gfx.test;

import everything;

public class Ball extends View  {   
RectF lol;
Paint paint, lpaint;
Bitmap bitmap;
Canvas canvas;
private float ballx = 150; 
private float bally = 140;
private double speedx = 0;  
private double speedy = 0; //ignore  
private double accx, accy=0;
private float rad = 15;
private float mult = 0.5f;
private float friction = -0.001f;
private double xv, yv, xS, yS;
private long ltm = -1;
int width, height;
int xmax, ymax;
int xmin, ymin;

public Ball(Context context) {
    super(context);
    lol = new RectF();
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    lpaint = new Paint();
    lpaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);                


}
public double getSpeedX()
{
    return this.speedx;
}
public double getSpeedY()
{
    return this.speedy;
}
public void setSpeedX(double x)
{
    this.speedx = x;
}
public void setSpeedY(double y)
{
    this.speedy = y;
}
public void setColor(int c)
{
    paint.setColor(c);
}
public float getRad()
{
    return this.rad;
}
public void setRad(float rad)
{
    this.rad = rad;
}
public void setAX(double accx)
{
    this.accx = accx;
}
public void setAY(double accy)
{
    this.accy = accy;
}
public float getX()
{
    return this.ballx;
}
public void setX(float ballx)
{
    this.ballx = ballx;
}
public float getY()
{
    return this.bally;
}
public void setY(float bally)
{
    this.bally = bally;
}
public void moveBall()  {


    xv = accx * mult;
    yv = accy * mult;

    ballx -= xv * mult;
    bally -= yv * mult;

    ballx +=speedx;
    bally +=speedy;


    /*ballx +=speedx;
    bally +=speedy;*/

    // Collision detection
    if (ballx + rad > xmax) {
         speedx = -speedx;     
         ballx = xmax-rad;
    }         
    else if (ballx - rad < 0) {
         speedx = -speedx;
         ballx = rad;
    }
    if (bally + rad > 2*ymax/3) {
        speedy = -speedy;
        bally = 2*ymax/3 - rad;


    } 

    else if (bally - rad < 0) {
         speedy = -speedy;
         bally =  rad;
    }                           

    try {
        Thread.sleep(20);
    }   catch(InterruptedException e) {}

    invalidate();   

}
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthM, int heightM)
{
    width = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthM);
    height = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightM);
    xmax = width-1;
    ymax = height-1;
    xmin = 0;
    ymin = 0;
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);


}
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    lol.set(ballx - rad, bally-rad, ballx + rad, bally+rad);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 2*height/3, width, 2*height/3, lpaint);
    /*canvas.drawOval(lol, paint);*/
    canvas.drawCircle(ballx, bally, rad, paint);
    canvas.drawText(xv + " " + yv, 0, height/2, lpaint);
    canvas.save();
    moveBall();
    canvas.restore();

}



}
```

This is my ball class, and my main activity would be:

```
package perseus.gfx.test;
import everything;
public class GfxActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener, OnItemSelectedListener, SensorEventListener {

ViewGroup.LayoutParams vg = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(-1, -1);
double velx, vely;
double x, y;
float radi;
double finx, finy;
float finrad;

long lastSensorUpdate = -1;
SensorManager sm;
static double ux, uy;   //initial ball velocity
SeekBar velo, rad;
Spinner colour;
Ball ball, tester;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

    ball = new Ball(this);
    tester = new Ball(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    addContentView(ball, vg);

    addContentView(tester, vg);
    sm = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sm.registerListener(this, sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    colour = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.color);
    colour.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> aa = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.colors, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    colour.setAdapter(aa);
    velo = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.vel);
    velo.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);  
    rad = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.rad);
    rad.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    ux = ball.getSpeedX();
    uy = ball.getSpeedY();   
    radi = ball.getRad();
    tester.setSpeedX(5);
    tester.setSpeedY(3);
    tester.setX(0);
    tester.setY(0);
    tester.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
}
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seeker, int arg1, boolean arg2) {       
    switch(seeker.getId())
    {
    case R.id.vel:
        x = ball.getSpeedX();
        y = ball.getSpeedY();

        if(x<0)
            finx = -ux-arg1;            
        else if(x >= 0)
            finx = ux+arg1; 

        if(y<0) 
            finy = -uy-arg1;        
        else if(finy>=0)
            finy = uy+arg1;

        ball.setSpeedX(finx);
        ball.setSpeedY(finy);
        break;

    case R.id.rad:          
        finrad = radi + arg1;
        ball.setRad(finrad);
        break;
    }   
}
@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
    //nothing lol
}
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
    //nothing lol
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
        long id) {
    switch(position)
    {
    case 0:
        ball.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        break;
    case 1:
        ball.setColor(Color.RED);
        break;
    case 2:
        ball.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        break;
    case 3:
        ball.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        break;
    }

}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

}
@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorevent) {
    if(sensorevent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION)
    {
            ball.setAX(sensorevent.values[2]);
            ball.setAY(sensorevent.values[1]);                          
    }

        if((Math.pow(ball.getX() - tester.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(ball.getY() - tester.getY(), 2)) <= (ball.getRad() + tester.getRad())*(ball.getRad() + tester.getRad()))
        {

                /*tester.setSpeedX(-1*tester.getSpeedX());
                tester.setSpeedY(-1*tester.getSpeedY());*/
        }
    }

}
```

Ball and Tester are my two balls, Ball is controlled by the accelerometer. I'm aware that the code isn't very efficient, but I thought I'll work on implementing the collision first.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to consider a couple things before you can refine your collision algorithm - is the collision to be an elastic collision? Can you treat the two balls as point sources? Either way your momentum vectors will be conserved, so you can use Newton's `P initial = P final` to determine the new vectors.

The two balls are likely overlapping because the rate at which you are running your collision detection algorithm is slower than the rate at which you change the position of the balls.

If you post a code sample, we can help you better.

Comment: Well, I forgot to mention that I wanted to treat them both as equal masses (for now). I've posted my code.

Comment: Well treating the masses as the same will simplify your conservation of momentum equations but you will still need to decide whether they are elastic or inelastic collisions (whether or not kinetic energy is conserved).

About your other problem with the collision detection, the first thing I notice is that you do your collision detection after you move the balls. This may be part of the problem, as when two balls are just about to intersect, you might move them closer together, so it appears they overlap before you get a chance to test collisions.

Comment: I wanted an elastic collision. Where do you suggest I put my collision detection code?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have xVel1, yVel1, xVel2, yVel2; xPos1, yPos1, xPos2, yPos2; mass1, mass2; after detecting the collision:

```
double theta = Math.atan2(yPos1-yPos2, xPos1-xPos2);
double c = Math.cos(theta);
double s = Math.sin(theta);
double xVel1prime = xVel1*c+yVel1*s;
double xVel2prime = xVel2*c+yVel2*s;
double yVel1prime = yVel1*c-xVel1*s;
double yVel2prime = yVel2*c-xVel2*s;
double P = (mass1*xVel1prime+mass2*xVel2prime);
double V = (xVel1prime-xVel2prime);
double v2f = (P+mass1*V)/(mass1+mass2);
double v1f = v2f-xVel1prime+xVel2prime;
xVel1prime = v1f;
xVel2prime = v2f;

xVel1 = xVel1prime*c-yVel1prime*s;
xVel2 = xVel2prime*c-yVel2prime*s;
yVel1 = yVel1prime*c+xVel1prime*s;
yVel2 = yVel2prime*c+xVel2prime*s;
//velocities updated
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, both the balls start travelling extremely fast between the corners. I forgot to mention, I'm considering both unit masses. I've posted my code.

Comment: That's probably because the collision is detected again and again right after the balls changed their speeds. Try adding something like "collision detected -> wait for 100 ms -> start looking for a new collision"